# Sending email in heroku host since laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, email, heroku

I am trying to send an email confirmation account from a web application made in laravel 5.4, I have tested in my localhost and it is sent correctly, but when deployed in heroku throws me this error:

```
Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:

Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530-5.5.1 
Authentication Required. 

Learn more at
530 5.5.1 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/14257 w10sm15831823wjk.18 - 
gsmtp"
```

I have already configured the application key from gmail, even the tests from the localhost are positive, but since heroku fails to send the email.

These are my settings in the .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=micorreo@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mvallokmzmszjtwk
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure add-on mail in heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp